# Call a function with dynamic paramter

Tags: python, reusability, calling-convention

If I had a function name stored in a variable, how can I know inside the function the name of the variable used to call it?

e.g.:

> ```
> var_name = function1
> var_name("3")
>
> def function1(self, params=""):
>   print("the parameter is " + params + "called by" + VARIABLENAME)
> ```

I would have an output like:

*the paramter is 3 called by var_name*

Thanks for the support

Comment: You can't because you might have multiple variables pointing to the same function object; but why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a dictionary with association between "name" and function_name to execute. Some different "name" referred to functions that are the same one with each other except for a string parameter that is the same of the variable "name".

Comment: It looks like you need separate functions for your use case.

Comment: This is what I thought, but i don't know much about python.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that on python, but you could do something like this to get the current function:

```
import inspect

def function1(n):
  print("the parameter is " + n + " called by " + inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).function)

function1("3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the calling function and additionally lookup all defined functions using `globals()`:

```
import inspect
import types

def function1(n):
    alias = getCallingAliases(inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).function)
    print("the parameter is " + n + " called by " + alias)

def getCallingAliases(realFn):
    for k, v in globals().items():
        if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
            # k == function or alias
            # v == original function
            aliasName = v.__name__
            if realFn != k and realFn == aliasName:
                return k
    return '<unknown>'

var_name = function1
var_name("3")
```

Out:

```
the parameter is 3 called by var_name
```

**Note**: That's not error prone and might need to be adjusted to your needs (regarding classes, imported function from other modules, ...)